# Getting SystemCheckError using inlines in django, Can't identify source

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

For the life of me, I cannot find a way to solve this, I don't really know what I'm doing wrong with the inlines.

I'm using django 1.8 as well as django-nested-inline 0.3.4.

Here's the contents of the models.py file:

```
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.fields import CharField, TextField, IntegerField
from django.utils import timezone

# lectura de sensor, no incluye datos, solo fecha y datos apuntan aquí
# también apunta a la pieza y el sensor asignado


class lectura(models.Model):
    lectura_nom = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    sensor_asign = models.ForeignKey('sensor_asignado')
    pieza = models.ForeignKey('pieza')

    verificacion = models.BooleanField()
    fecha_hora = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.lectura_nom

    def lectura_de_hoy(self):
        return self.fecha_hora >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

# pieza asignada al sensor, cambia de acuerdo a hroario de produccion
class pieza(models.Model):
    pieza_nom = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    paquete =models.ForeignKey('paquete')
    ultima = models.BooleanField()
    no_de_seq = models.IntegerField()
    description= models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pieza_nom

# paquetes incluyen puras piezas únicas al paquete
class paquete(models.Model):
    paquete_nom = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    no_de_piezas = models.IntegerField()
    no_de_medibles = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.paquete_nom


#lugar donde se encuentra el rack, importante para permisos de usuario
class area(models.Model):
    area_nom = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.area_nom

# rack del cual fue sacada la pieza    
class linea(models.Model):
    linea_nom = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    area = models.ForeignKey('area')
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.linea_nom

# sensor del cual se sacó la lectura
class sensor_asignado(models.Model):
    sensor_nom = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    linea = models.ForeignKey('linea')
    sensor_tipo = models.ForeignKey('tipo_de_sensor')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sensor_nom

# sensor puede incluir varias configuraciones de envio de datos    
class tipo_de_sensor(models.Model):
    tipo_de_sen_nom = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    descripcion=models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tipo_de_sen_nom

# diferentes datos para el sensor de tipo especificado anteriormente
# cada dato apunta hacia una lectura    
class salidas_de_sensor(models.Model):
    salida_nom = CharField(max_length = 20)
    descripcion = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.salida_nom

class datos_o(models.Model):
    dato_no = IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    salida_de_sensor = models.ForeignKey('salidas_de_sensor')
    lectura = models.ForeignKey('lectura')

    def __str__(self):
        r_string = str(self.dato_no)
        return r_string

# advertencias, apunta a un tipo y una lectura
class adv(models.Model):
    adv_no = IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    lectura = models.ForeignKey('lectura')
    adv_tipo = models.ForeignKey('adv_tipo')

    def __str__(self):
        adv_string = str(self.adv_no)
        return adv_string

# diferentes tipo de advertencias posibles
class adv_tipo(models.Model):
    adv_tip = CharField(max_length = 20)
    descrip_adv = TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.adv_tip
```

Here's the contents of my admin.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from nested_inline.admin import NestedStackedInline, NestedModelAdmin
from mainscreen.models import *

class AreaInline(NestedStackedInline):
    model = area
    extra = 1
    fk_name = area

class LineaInLine(NestedStackedInline):
    model = linea
    extra = 1
    fk_name = linea
    inlines = [AreaInline]

class SensorInLine(NestedModelAdmin):
    model = sensor_asignado
    inlines = [LineaInLine]


    admin.site.register(lectura)
admin.site.register(sensor_asignado, SensorInLine)
admin.site.register(salidas_de_sensor)
admin.site.register(pieza)
admin.site.register(paquete)
admin.site.register(area)
admin.site.register(linea)
admin.site.register(tipo_de_sensor)
admin.site.register(adv)
admin.site.register(adv_tipo)
admin.site.register(datos_o)
```

And here's the error I'm getting:

```
Performing system checks...

SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
<class 'mainscreen.admin.LineaInLine'>: (admin.E202) 'mainscreen.linea' has no field named '<class 'mainscreen.models.linea'>'.

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
```

Anyway, if anyone can identify a solution to this problem, I'll be really thankfull.

Have a good day.

EDIT:

Okay, now I have another problem entirely, and I believe it's more of a design problem.

The way I want the information to be displayed in the admin, is:

```
when a new Sensor Asignado is created, have the option to choose from a drop downn menu in the following order of hierarchy:
    Area
    Linea (filtered by Area chosen)
    Sensor (Filtered by Linea chosen)
```

Again, I've been wrecking myself trying to get this right for a while, and any help is much appreciated.

Thank you, have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a string for `fk_name`:

```
fk_name = 'linea'
```

As an aside, I recommend that you use the Django convention, and name your models `SensorAsignado` and `Linea` instead of `sensor_asignado` and `linea`. It will make your code easier to understand for other Django users.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I missed that, it's kinda embarrassing, really, Thanks for the tip on the Django convention for class names.

Comment: This solution got the application running, but it's not exactly the thing I'm looking my app to do, so thanks a lot, but could you please help me out a bit more?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an answer for that, you might have more luck if you ask a new question.